# Why is the head.php file suddenly not found?

Tags: joomla3.8

I don't know what's changed, but I'm getting this error message when trying to access site:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/homepages/1/d565826656/htdocs/maldonsharks/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php

I've looked around a few forums and several suggest that the "head.php" reference is no longer valid and should point to "/src…/HeadRenderer.php".

I tried updating the two files mentioned (error.php and offline.php), but then I get:

> 404 article not found

However, I can find no issue with any published articles and nothing has been added recently, so I don't understand what could have changed for it to go wrong.

Comment: Have you ensured you're using the latest version of th Cloudbase 3 template? You should be running version 1.0.8 which fixes some critical issues on Joomla 3.8

Answer (score 1):

The two errors have completely different (albeit related) causes.  The fatal error is caused by the fact you had an old Gantry template with a call to a file that got moved in the great src directory migration of 3.7(? I think.) So that fatal error in the error.php has been sitting there ready to happen since you upgraded you Joomla to 3.7+. The 404 error exposed the 500 error but has nothing to do with it.

So is every page on the site a 404 including the home page? Something must be happening but without seeing the site or knowing any further details it's a bit difficult to guess what's going on.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback. I was beginning to see that the error message was a latent defect waiting to happen, as you say a result of the directory migration of 3.7. The site is http://www.maldonsharks.co.uk Is there any way to find out if a specific article or it's contents are causing a problem. I've been through and looked at the current articles and nothing looks to contain anything out of the ordinary, a few jpg's and some links but nothing else.

Comment: I went to the link but the 500 error was back in place. You can probably just rem out that require_once statement as the class should be auto included.

Comment: Now your homepage is a 404 but everything else is normal.  http://maldonsharks.co.uk/about-us.html  for instance works.  Is your homepage menu item a featured article or single article or something else?

Comment: I think I'm finally getting it back. The article on the home page had an expiry date which had recently expired. Clearing this date and setting the article back to active seems to have cleared the problem. I think I may have cleared some of the templates and so the presentation looks a bit odd at the moment - the menu bar is displayed in two places - but I'm sure I can clean this up.

Comment: Many, Many thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction to fix this. Thankyou:-)